# NSDateFormatter - Adding a Year?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdateformatter

I have the following code which is simply getting the current date and converting it to the format YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz

```
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
        NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:currentTimeZone];

        NSString *time = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

        NSLog(@"TIME IS %@", time);
```

With this, I'm getting the following log output:

```
2014-12-30 00:20:38.987 MYAPPNAME[953:229825] TIME IS 2015-12-30 00:20:38 CST
```

Can someone tell me why the output is showing as 2015, rather than 2014 as it should be?

Comment: Check your system or device date

Comment: Use `yyyy` instead of `YYYY` in the date format

Comment: @AdamTheRaysFan:  Please accept and upvote the answer, whichever been helpful to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`yyyy` specifies the calendar year, whereas `YYYY` specifies the year (of “Week of Year”)

you must change your `dateformatter` style from

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
```

to

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
```

for your reference, check this [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html)

Answer (score 1):

change your date formate

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss zzz"];
        NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        [dateFormatter setTimeZone:currentTimeZone];

        NSString *time = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

        NSLog(@"TIME IS %@", time);
```

For more details, about NSDateFormatter, read this:

http://realmacsoftware.com/blog/working-with-date-and-time